# Can objects manage their own destruction (using ARC)?

Tags: objective-c

I have a controlling parent class that needs to perform several actions, these actions typically have a very short lifespan. I'm using a Factory class to create these objects and have some questions about how to best manage their demise and if more than one can safely co-exist. Here some example pseudo code:

```
@interface parent
@property (strong, nonatomic) abstractChild*  action;
- (abstractChild*) makeConcreteChildOfType:(Type)type;
- (void) performActionA;
- (void) performActionB;
- (void) performActionC;

...
- (void) performActionA;
{
    self.action = [self makeConcreteChildOfType:A];
    [self.action doYourThing];
}

- (void) performActionB;
{
    self.action = [self makeConcreteChildOfType:B];
    [self.action doYourThing];
}
```

I have quite a lot of different types of actions and each child action class knows what it has to do and when its finished doing it.
I could create separate properties for each different type of concrete action instead of having one abstract property, and have each child object inform the parent when its finished via a delegate, however that's starting to get a little messy especially when the fact that multiple actions of the same type could potentially be active at once (which would require arrays of pointers to objects of each type). Therefore I'm wondering if/how the child objects can manage themselves, specifically their own destruction.

If each object looked something like this:

```
@implementation ChildObjectA

-(void) doYourThing
{
   [self retain];
   do something
}

- (void) OnCompletion
{
    [self release];
}
```

Then is this safe to do? - could the parent class create multiple objects of the same type and they all live for as long as each is needed and effectively are deleting themselves when done and they can exist in parallel and delete themselves when done without issue?

There is presumably no need for the action property of the parent class, but if it was kept then I'd like to confirm there's no problems with memory management that arise? I presume not as each time self.action is assigned to ARC will release the associated child object but it won't be deleted until the child object releases itself?

Comment: You can have them safely delete themselves by storing a `__strong` reference to themselves as an ivar, and setting that to nil when they are complete. As far as I know, that's the only `safe` way to do it in ARC.

Comment: Thanks. Could that ivar be of type id and made a member of the root class, or should it be a specific type and a member of each individual class? Or it makes no difference? And presumably it can be assigned to in the object's init?

Comment: it doesn't matter, typically I use `id` because it's simpler than the name of the class, and yes, you can assign it wherever.

Comment: While Richard is completely correct about how self-ownership works, what you're describing is very likely better managed with an NSOperationQueue or dispatch_queue. This is the kind of problem that those tools are designed to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly *possible* for an object to own itself, but the cases where it's truly necessary are few and far between. I don't think this is one of them.

I think the solution that you've called "too messy" is in fact the best one. It's also, to my mind, quite *simple* and clean. The factory keeps a collection of action objects.* When an action object is done, it informs the factory, which cleans it up. This is similar to the activity of an `NSOperationQueue` -- the queue takes ownership of the operations.

```
@implementation Factory
{
    NSMutableArray * listOfAllActions;
}

- (void) performActionA;
{
    Action * newAction = [self makeConcreteChildOfType:A];
    [listOfAllActions addObject:newAction];
    [newAction setOwner:self];
    [newAction doYourThing];
}

// And similarly for other "performAction..." methods
```

Each action, then, sends a simple "all done!" message to its owner when it completes:

```
@interface AbstractChild

@property (weak) Factory * owner;

//...

@implementation AbstractChild

@synthesize owner;

- (void)cleanupAfterCompletion
{
    // Subclasses can override this to do more cleanup

    // Message the action's owner, passing self so it knows which action
    [[self owner] actionHasCompleted:self];
}
```

Then, back in Factory,

```
- (void)actionHasCompleted: (AbstractAction *)action
{
    // Other cleanup if necessary

    // Delete action
    [listOfAllActions removeObjectIdenticalTo:action];
}
```

If for some reason you dislike the action having a direct pointer back to the factory, you could use [notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html), but those are generally for times when the two objects have a much weaker relationship than this.

---

*That's the reality of the situation -- you are creating multiple objects. In fact, to be frank, your idea of having one property for potentially multiple objects seems messy to *me*.

Comment: Thanks, any tweaks needed regarding the weak specifier and fact this is going to run on 4 as well as 5? Just change it to unsafe_unretained?

Comment: It's `assign` for properties, but yes. There's not really anything gained from `weak` (over `assign`) here anyways. (I.e., since the object at the other end of `owner` is guaranteed to be alive while this object is, we're only using `weak` to avoid a cycle, not for the auto-nil feature of `weak`.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a article that might be a solution to what you are trying to do... It is basically saying to use the weak qualifier which automatically sets the object to nil if its reference zeroes...
http://thinkvitamin.com/code/ios/ios-5-automatic-reference-counting-arc/ (Credit goes to author of this article)

Comment: Thanks but what would be the trigger that causes its reference to go to 0 in the first place? That still needs to happen somewhere within the object itself, and how  else to do that is not by setting a reference to itself to nil?